# error: im not able to convert my images from bgr to rgb: TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

Tags: python, opencv, artificial-intelligence

***#error: im not able to convert my images from bgr to rgb***

```
images = []
path = 'E:\subjects\AI\Face-Mask-Detection-master\without-mask-detections'
listimages=os.listdir(path)
encode_list = []

for img in listimages:
        images.append(img)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)
        encode_list.append(encode)

print(images)
#encodeListKnown= find_encoding(images)
#print(len(encodeListKnown))
```

Answer (score 0):

The file name you are using (img) does not include the full path and cannot be opened. Also, your code does not open the image file. You should build the full path and open it using:

```
for file in listimages:
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, file))
    images.append(img)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)
    encode_list.append(encode)
```